# How to extract a calculated value from cache when the input is a list of values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny App where I used machine learning algorithms and these latter used a lot of compute power. I would like to use the function **bindCache** for extracting the calculated results. However, when my inputs are ordered in a different way but the results stay the same, my algorithms recalculate everything, which I don't want. Here is a simple example to illustrate my problem:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("x", "x", seq(10), multiple = TRUE)
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , br()
    , verbatimTextOutput("txt")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    r <- reactive({
      message("Doing expensive computation...")
      Sys.sleep(2)
      sort(as.numeric(input$x))
    }) %>% bindCache(input$x)
    
    output$txt <- renderText(r())
  }
  
)
```

For example, if I enter 2 and then 5, the input is a c(2,5) and the sum 7. The result is saved if I enter again 2 and then 5. However, if I enter 5 and then 2, the result is recalculated again for the same result. How can I avoid the recalculation if the list of values contains the same values but not ordered?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works:

```
bindCache(sum(as.numeric(input$x)))
```

Comment: Hello Stéphane, Thank you for your answer. I noticed that my output is not correct. My output is also a list of values, not a single value. If I replace sum(as.numeric(input$x)) by sort(as.numeric(input$x)), your tip does not work anymore. Do you have any idea how to solve this trouble?

Comment: @Quynh-MaiChu Sorry, no idea :-(

Comment: @Quynh-MaiChu Are you sure it doesn't work ? i have the impression it works.

Comment: Yes, it does not work for me. It seems it's recalculating

Comment: @Quynh-MaiChu Did you also replace `sum` with `sort` in `bindCache`? You must.

Comment: Yes, I replaced it. I tried it again. It seems to work. I will try with my use case because it takes more time to run. BTW, do you know how to save sort(as.numeric(input$x)) in a variable?

Comment: I tried on my use case. It seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities are using `bindCache` with a pre-computed key or `memoise` with pre-computed input. To see them work, for example:

1. Type "A B C" in the input box then press the button.
2. Type "C B A" in the input box then press the button.

Using `bindCache`:

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("text_input", label = "input"),
    tableOutput("table_output"),
    actionButton("start_button", label = "calculate")
  ),

  server = function(input, output){

    sort_input = reactive({
      sort(str_split(input$text_input, " ")[[1]])
    })

    calc_output = reactive({
      Sys.sleep(2)
      sort_input()
    }) %>%
      bindCache({sort_input()}) %>%
      bindEvent(input$start_button)

    observe({
      output$table_output = renderTable(as.matrix(system.time(calc_output())), rownames = T)
    })
  }
)
```

Using `memoise`:

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(memoise)

sort_func = function(input)
{
  return(sort(str_split(input$text_input, " ")[[1]]))
}

output_func = function(input) { 
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
output_func_memoised = memoise(output_func)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("text_input", label = "input"),
    tableOutput("table_output"),
    actionButton("start_button", label = "calculate")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output){
    
    calc_output = reactive({
      output_func_memoised(sort_func(input))
    }) %>%
      bindEvent(input$start_button)
    
    observe({
      output$table_output = renderTable(as.matrix(system.time(calc_output())), rownames = T)
    })
  }
)
```